# A public folder which always available

Tags: android

Is there a folder which always available in Android. I know `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` but I need to check its state. It means, sometimes that folder can be unavaliable. I don't want to use internal app storage because I (and customers) need to reach files from a pc. So is there a provided folder which always avaliable in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External storage is what you want. It is the storage that is accessible from a PC. The reason it can be unavailable is because when you have the folder open on a PC, it becomes unavailable for the device to write to it. So in that case, you would just notify the user to unplug their USB cable and close the folder on their PC before proceeding.

The [Android docs state this here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> Caution: External storage can become unavailable if the user mounts
>   the external storage on a computer or removes the media, and there's
>   no security enforced upon files you save to the external storage. All
>   applications can read and write files placed on the external storage
>   and the user can remove them.

External storage is the only option for what you are wanting to do, unless you write to a network location (like a database, etc) and then somehow allow the user to access the data there.

Comment: it says "or removes the media". So for some devices if customer does not using a sd card, it will be unavaliable, right?

Comment: It varies from device to device. Some devices use a physical SD card for external storage. For devices that don't have an SD card, there is an internal "external" storage within the device. It's confusing, I know. But if a device doesn't have an SD card, the internal partition should still be available for you to write to, as long as it is not currently open on a PC.

Comment: I know some device does not have sd slot, and there is a reserved area  in internal storage which work as external storage. But for example if a device have sd slot and user do not using a sd card. In this case `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` will return an valid path? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes that should be correct. For instance, I test on my HTC One M8, which has an SD slot, but I don't have an SD card in the slot. So when I access external storage, it gives me the internal partition instead. I've never used my device with an SD card inserted, so I'm not sure what would happen, but I would expect the SD card to become my new external storage. Either way, an external storage SOMEWHERE should always be available to you, as long as it is not currently being browsed through USB.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.